# Как разрешить пользователям домена устанавливать шрифты?

Tags: active-directory

Как разрешить пользователям домена устанавливать шрифты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гуляло в интернете [решение](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b5cf8f10-b864-4987-b803-002aad6aa39d/-?forum=ws2008r2ru)

Comment: Да я уже нашел и мануал выложил: http://sebeadmin.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?id=583p.s. руткот что-то не особо забит спецами в отличии от хешкода.

Comment: хешкод не особо забит спецами в отличии от stackoverflow...

Comment: Это точно, но вот только стек - на англ. языке, а с ним не все дружат. )

Comment: Зря английский друг очень хороший , прибыльный как минимум.